# Flutter lint - Don't override fields

Tags: flutter, lint

I am trying to resolve the lint rule warning, Don't override fields and I cannot seem to crack it.
May I please get some assistance on how to go about it

My code:

```
 @override
  final Key? key; // LINT warning is caused by key

  FeedViewArticle(
    this.articleId,
    this.image, {
   
    this.key,
    
  }) : super(key: key);
```

I tried removing the @override and it still does not work, your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove the field entirely. It inherited it from the super class so it already has it. No need to define it again. You can write the constructor as:

```
  FeedViewArticle(
    this.articleId,
    this.image, {
    super.key,
  });
```